# firebase.js:12 Uncaught ReferenceError: initializeApp is not defined

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

I am have having trouble connecting with Firebase with VisualStudiocode (store my blog posts). I am receiving these messages when I try to save a blog post on my localhost server.[image]

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Here is my code for editor.html.

```
<script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script defer src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/9.6.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>

   
    <script src="js/firebase.js"></script>
    <script src="js/editor.js"></script>
```

Here is my code for editor.js.

```
const blogTitleField = document.querySelector('.title');
const articleField = document.querySelector('.article');

// banner

const bannerImage = document.querySelector('#banner-upload');
const banner = document.querySelector(".banner");
let bannerPath;

const publishBtn = document.querySelector('.publish-btn');
const uploadInput = document.querySelector('#image-upload');

bannerImage.addEventListener('change', () => {
    uploadImage(bannerImage, "banner");
})

uploadInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
    uploadImage(uploadInput, "image");
})

const uploadImage = (uploadFile, uploadType) => {
    const [file] = uploadFile.files;
  
    if(file && file.type.includes("image")){
        const formdata = new FormData();
       
        formdata.append('image', file);
        
        fetch('/upload', {
            method: 'post',
            body: formdata

        }).then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            if(uploadType == "image"){
                addImage(data, file.name);
                }else{
                bannerPath = `${location.origin}/${data}`;
            banner.style.backgroundImage = `url("${bannerPath}")`;

            }
        })
    } else{
        alert("upload Image only");
    }
}

const addImage = (imagepath, alt) => {
    let curPos = articleField.selectionStart;
    let textToInsert = `\r![${alt}](${imagepath})\r`;
    articleField.value = articleField.value.slice(0, curPos) + textToInsert + articleField.value.slice(curPos);
}

let months = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"];

publishBtn.addEventListener('click',() => {
    if(articleField.value.length && blogTitleField.value.length){

        let letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
        let blogTitle = blogTitleField.value.split(" ").join("-");
        let id = '';
        for(let i = 0; i < 4; i++){
            id += letters[Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length)];
        }

        let docName = `${blogTitle}-${id}`;
        let date = new Date(); //for published at info
     
        db.collection("blogs").doc(docName).set({
            title: blogTitleField.value,
            article: articleField.value,
            bannerImage: bannerPath,
            publishedAt: `${date.getDate()} ${months[date.getMonth()]} ${date.getFullYear()}`
        })
        
        .then(() => {
            console.log('date entered');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log.error(err);
        })
    }
})
```

Here is my code for firebase.js.

```
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AI....",
    authDomain: "blogging-website.....",
    projectId: "blogging-website-b2f07",
    storageBucket: "blogging-website......",
    messagingSenderId: "2......",
    appId: "1:2........"
};


 const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
// firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);


let db = firebase.firestore();
```

Answer (score 0):

Firebase JavaScript SDK versions v9 and above use a modular syntax, with top-level functions to access most functionality.

Firebase JavaScript SDK versions v8 and before, use an object model, with most functionality accessed through top-level `firebase.someproduct()` objects.

Your code mixes these two SDK models, which won't work unless you may very close attention. I recommend using either the traditional object syntax, or using the new modular syntax, not both.

Your last snippet in v9/modular syntax would be:

```
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = getFirestore(app);
```

This is all quite well covered in the Firebase documentation on [getting started with Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart) and the [upgrade guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade), so I recommend spending some time with those.